# how determine node version by looking at code repo

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

By looking at a node js application, is it possible to deduct
what node version (4 or 6) it's aimed at. ?

I'm looking at this btw:
https://github.com/jorditost/node-postgres-restapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great habit to put the version of the node inside the `package.json` file, but in this case there seems to be no reference to the subject.

In general, there is no way to know which version of node this code originally written to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know this unless the developer specifically stated this in the Readme.

Or, findinging depreciated methods, or tools.